# What is the right site to ask about plugin customization?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, superuser

Like many people, I rely on plugins such as Superfish, Nivo Slider, Google Charts, etc. for Web design.

Which Stackexchange site is the best to ask customization questions on these plugins? I am not talking about writing code (in which case Stackoverflow would be my choice), I am just talking about questions on the out of the box configuration options, or alternatives to a given plugin.

I have found [older, similar questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94132/what-can-we-do-about-questions-asking-for-plugin-script-recommendations), but people seem to have divergent opinions. I'd like to know the "official line" (I tagged this question "support", not "discussion").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost: [**Stack Exchange isn't a forum**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum). [It's a *network* of ***Question and Answer sites***](http://stackexchange.com). They are fundamentally different from forums. (Check the **[FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)** and the **[/about](https://stackoverflow.com/about)** pages for more information on that). Now that we got that out of the way:

I think your best bet is on **[Web Masters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)**, that's assuming the plugin discussion is web-based, and you're looking for extra configurations or settings.

If you're interested in extending them code-wise, [**Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/) is the place for you.

Comment: Point taken, I have removed the term "forum" from the question.

Comment: Actually even though this site isn't a internet forum, it is still a forum as in a place for discussion. So I wouldn't go all **bold** on people for using such a term.