# Guidance on recently added jquery tag, jquery-jtable

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags, jquery

Question: I recently added a new [`jquery-jtable`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-jtable/info) tag and started re-tagging related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-jtable) accordingly. Is this right? Should I proceed?

Background: I often search for stray questions tagged [`JTable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtable). I recently started seeing collisions with questions about [`jTable`](http://jtable.org/), a [`jQuery`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) plugin. I know little about either. This question about another plugin seemed similar:

- [*New tag request jquery-isotope*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94418/163188)

but I was concerned about these potential problems:

- [*Complaint about jQuery question tagging*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48818/163188)
- [*How do you feel about “Help me with this jQuery plugin” type questions?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84848/163188)

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878/282094)    https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/282094   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/282094

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I recently added a new [jquery-jtable](/questions/tagged/jquery-jtable) tag and started re-tagging related questions accordingly. Is this right? Should I proceed?

Absolutely!  If you know that you need to create a new tag, finding other questions to which the new tag applies is going to help the New Tag Deletionists understand that the creator has given the tag some thought and has shown effort towards making the tag useful.

In this specific instance, a new tag is totally called for.  Nobody likes an ambiguous tag.

Comment: OK, I just didn't want to exacerbate any existing `jquery` problems. I appreciate the feedback.