# When to burninate

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-system

Upon seeing [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268187/1007939), I took a look at the [user](/questions/tagged/user) tag, and it currently has 1366 unanswered questions, and 4326 total questions. Seeing as that's quite a lot, I thought I'd help with the burnination (am I correct in thinking the burnination is done by users?). However, I can't really tell when the burnination should start or when it's "approved"? I found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256149/when-should-a-burninate-request-be-actioned), but there are no answers.

Comment: Just a passing observation: the community's threshold for burning what they consider bad tags is [much lower than it should be](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260537/102937).  That's one of the reasons SE requires us to burn these tags one question at a time: to introduce some friction.

Comment: As to the burnination of [user] one question at a time, I think your time could be better spent.  I also think most of the upvotes on that question are tongue-in-cheek swipes at users of computer software (a thinly veiled nod towards PEBKAC).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was under the impression that was how it was done...?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Before you start *doing* anything, **put a little bit of thought into the request**:

### Does this tag even need to be burninated?

There are a *lot* of [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)s posted to various meta sites that are... To put it gently... **A complete and utter waste of everyone's time.** Some folks will seemingly post a request for any tag they come across that isn't interesting to them personally - and then try to justify it with some hand-waving about a lack of experts.

Here are the criteria I try to use when deciding whether or not to *completely eliminate a tag from the system:*

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

   Tags which fail these tests - [commonly referred to as "meta tags"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) - are effectively meaningless, and *can* be actively harmful. You may have to do some research here: I've seen folks call tags "meta" when they were perfectly relevant and unambiguous, simply because the name-caller had no idea what the tag *meant*. Don't forget to update the tag wiki if you find it lacking...
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   This is kinda self-explanatory; Stack Overflow doesn't need a [kittens](/questions/tagged/kittens) tag, at least not until someone releases a hot new framework and names it "Kittens". All that a blatantly off-topic tag is gonna do is encourage blatantly off-topic *questions*, so removing it is good for everyone. Just be sure and do your homework: the last thing you want is to start removing tags only to be attacked by a bunch of angry kitten.js users.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   This covers a pretty big range of issues, from folks typing complete sentences into the tag entryfield causing useless tags to be applied, to folks just going overboard and applying once-reasonable tags to questions where it is only tangentially-relevant, to folks just finding two different terms for the same concept and using both of them. I'll usually start by looking at the "related tags" sidebar: there should be a few tags listed, but if any of them are *synonyms* then they should be [merged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retag-request); if that's not the case, then I'll start looking through questions to see how many of them are actually *about* the concept represented by the tag (which I should have a basic understanding of after step #1). If the tag is superfluous on the vast majority of questions where it is used, then it should go.

   Note that it's also worth checking the number of followers at this stage, mostly as a sanity-check: if a bunch of people are using a given tag to find questions they're interested in, then *just maybe* you missed something important when evaluating its value in context... Which brings me to:
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   This is related to #1, but can be a bit harder to identify because such tags will have very well-defined meanings but can be interpreted differently when different tags are applied. For instance, [a tree can be a data-structure or a visualization](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268170/burninate-the-tree-tag/268175#268175). You may have to look through quite a few questions to identify this situation, and again the related tags sidebar is your friend. Be aware though, this need only be a death sentence when one meaning is not far and away more common than all others - if a tag is used correctly most of the time, then just fix the instances where it isn't.

If you're thinking that these criteria are gonna be pretty tedious to evaluate on a tag with thousands of questions in it, then *you're absolutely right* - which is why I'm pretty *skeptical* toward a lot of these requests on those rare occasions I take time to do it. If you're thinking that it's not worth the effort for tags that generally don't seem to be causing any problems, **then you're sharper than half the folks throwing up these requests.** If it *looks* like pointless busywork, it probably *is* pointless busywork...

But sometimes, it's not. Sometimes, tags get in the way, add confusion, start fights, take the place of *better* tags...

## When can I start burninating the bad tag?

If you still have a solid case for burnination, then **raise the matter for discussion on that site's Meta.** You MUST have community consensus before burninating a tag with more than a few questions, and [Meta posts are required on Stack Overflow for tags with over 50 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356963/) (other communities may have different standards). Share your research, as outlined above, making your case for burnination. Use the tags [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) - and include the tag name in the title. **DO NOT** try for a two-fer - one tag per discussion.

If, after discussion, there is widespread agreement that a tag really *does* need to be burned, then...

### Start by cleaning up the edges

Bad tags are often harbingers of bad questions. So if you're about to remove a bad tag, start by removing the bad questions it collected: find closed questions and delete them, find downvoted questions and close them (if they warrant it), find poorly-written questions and re-write them (if they deserve it). You get the idea.

When a tag is merely ambiguous, sometimes it makes more sense to just replace it with another tag, or one of a number of other tags. This can be a quick way of turning a bad tag into a good one, or at least accomplishing something other than raw destruction when removing it.

This cleanup is easily the hardest, most time-consuming part of the process. Document your progress here on meta, so that others can see what you're up to and get involved - many hands make light work! And again, if you don't think it's worth doing then just drop it and move on to something else.

Once you're done closing / deleting / editing and retagging, you can finally start...

### Burninating

Now you're ready to actually remove the tag wholesale from a whole bunch of questions. Caveat: **don't bother with this unless you have [full editing rights](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).** Seriously - it's just a waste of everyone's time, because at this stage all that's left is mindless retagging - and for every question you mindlessly retag, at least two other people *with* full editing rights will have to approve your edit. So if you haven't yet gotten full editing rights, consider your job done - go answer some questions & come back when you can edit without approval.

Now, even if you *can* edit without approval... You probably shouldn't bother if there are more than a few dozen questions. Even if you have a few other people involved, 50-100 is probably the most you should bother with unless you're *down-right masochistic*. For tags that involve large numbers of questions, just flag the burninate-request and leave a note for the *moderators* that the cleanup is done. They'll pass this along to someone like me, I'll verify that you didn't lie about the sanity-checking and cleanup, click a button, and it'll be like the tag never existed...

[image]

Comment: Your caveat about full editing rights is what's holding me off for now. So I went and answered a question. :)

Comment: It truly is an utter waste of time @CDspace, even with full editing rights. Answering questions is far more useful anyday. [Do it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268125/2982225) only if it is justified and number of posts are less.

Comment: That's a very good answer — MSO does have a tendency to host burnination requests for just about any tag that isn't the name of a programming language (and even some that are). Your answer misses one step: **discuss it on meta**! Except in obvious cases (typo for an existing tag), all burninations should be discussed, and nobody should act until there is a **consensus** (not just one person saying it, but wait at least a week or so with no motivated opposition).

Comment: Regarding edits without full editing rights: so it's perfectly fine, **if you're doing more than removing one tag** but also fixing other tags, correcting spelling and formatting, improving the title, etc.

Comment: Correct on both counts, @gilles

Comment: https://github.com/ben-ng/kitten-js

Comment: Of course. There would be.

Comment: "`...find closed questions and delete them...`" and what if you can't VtD yet?

Comment: Then earn that privilege, @Sam.

Comment: @Sam you can help those who have VtD by down voting the bad closed questions and poor answers, which may trigger a roomba deletion, or lower the number of delete votes needed.  Poor answers showing up with an autoVLQ flag can also draw 20ks with more delete votes to clean up the crap.

Comment: Your mention of not rolling multiple requests into one seems intended to cover *unrelated* requests; is that correct? (*Related* tags being lumped together usually seems to work well enough in my experience, allowing for meaningful discussion on which tags in the complex should be left alone or cleaned up vs simply purged by hand.)

Comment: "Related" is fuzzy, @nathan. A tag and its plural is fine; "all SQL operators that are also mathematical ops" is not.

Comment: @Shog9: Fair enough. Seems a bit more guidance on that would be nice, though, to emphasize that there has to be a lot of cohesion for it to work well.

Comment: When in doubt, don't double, @nathan. If that's too vague, then just don't.

Comment: There is a problem.  The close-brigade has decided that passing *one* of your list of 4 criteria is a good reason to close a tag: https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md -- is that intended?

Comment: Ideally, a good tag should meet all 4 criteria, @Yakk - although as I note above, #4 isn't necessarily a good reason to get rid of a tag, merely a sign that some retagging might need to be done.

Comment: Why does the image use Comic Sans MS?

Comment: At one point does a burniation request typically get an official response? What do you do once you have a request that clearly meets the criteria you listed here and is highly upvoted (50+ score, for example)? (I was thinking about [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349778/burn-the-entry-tag), by way of example).

Comment: Dumb question: what stuff can the community just do on their own and what needs to actually be approved? Can you do the magic wand thing to [disappear the "entry" tag from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349778/burn-the-entry-tag), for example? Is there some kind of score threshold where you can just assume that the community agrees, so you should just start the burniation process? (In the case of the "entry" tag on Stack Overflow, the proposal to burniate it has 52 upvotes and no downvotes and it clearly meets the criteria you mention here).

Comment: hey @EJoshuaS - for Stack Overflow, the mods try to keep these to a few at a time; see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-burninating-tags

Comment: "Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?" This is conflated with and in opposition to 4. If you ignore 4, then the answer to 3 might be yes even though it adds *different* information in different contexts. It's also much more subjective than we normally want on SE; every single word in a decently written post arguably adds meaning or clarity. Many tags are better suited as simply part of the title. This makes the criterion broad and difficult to evaluate. Furthermore, 4 appears to be a restatement of the "unambiguous" part of criterion 1, or at most one specific aspect of it.

Comment: Yeah, #s 1,2 and 4 are also not very useful if you only read the bold text, @jpmc26. I describe what I'm aiming for and how I apply it if you read on though. Keep in mind: this entire guide is aimed at making it *hard to burninate things* - in my experience, folks tend to propose getting rid of tags without doing even the most basic research into how those tags are used or what they're intended to mean. I and others frequently spend hours to days actually executing these requests; if you find this guide difficult, then please please *please* don't propose tag burnination.

Comment: "Yeah, #s 1,2 and 4 are also not very useful if you only read the bold text." That's fundamentally problematic if you intend for this set of questions to be applied verbatim across SE, [which appears to be the case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/1394393). Such a wide reaching policy needs *immediate* clarity.

Comment: Also, I find your response that I shouldn't propose burnination insulting and unwelcoming. When I approach burnination (even not my own), I look pretty hard at the tag and how it's used and whether there's consistency or if there's narrower meanings that should be made their own tags with better names or if there's broader tags it could be folded into. It does not necessarily represent a failing on my part if I suggest to you that the set of criteria you came up with is unclear and requires too much deciphering; it represents that there is probably a UX problem.

Comment: If you want to demonstrate thoroughness and care, start by reading the post you're responding to, @jpmc. I can't clarify something you won't read.

Comment: ...What? That... doesn't even make sense as an assertion. You wrote it. *Of course* you can revise it to be more clear. I really don't know what you could possibly mean by that, other than trying to imply, "Shut up and go away."

Comment: I've gone ahead and read the descriptions, I don't see anything that isn't in line with the problems I mentioned initially. 3 is still subjective to the point of being ill-defined. How do you determine whether a tag is "superfluous?" You give some examples of just outright bad tag usage, but that's different from whether it adds any useful info. It's going to depend on your opinion of what information should be conveyed by tags. It can also still add info if the tag is used for disparate concepts depending on the context; in other words, a failure in 4 can override a lack of failure in 3.

Comment: Ok, @jpmc - 5 comments in I still have no idea if you're struggling with a real problem or if you're just celebrating New year's Eve with a bout of pedantry. If you have a question or concern, please post a separate question, try to elaborate on it, and I'll do my best to clarify. Otherwise, I'm gonna just ignore this.