# Should the [Internet Explorer] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

The Stack Exchange Meta has the tag [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer).   The description is

> Questions about site's functionality issues (bugs, incompatibilities, feature requests) in any version of Internet Explorer.

I reported a [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377594/profile-description-text-extends-out-of-its-space-using-internet-explorer-11) for Internet Explorer, which to my surprise was quickly downvoted. A user pointed me to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208) which show which browsers are supported. He told me to "be aware of what is and isn't supported on the site".

Internet Explorer 11 was listed under supported browsers, but it had the following message:

> - Compatibility mode should be
>   disabled
> - This browser is mostly supported on a "because it works"
>   basis. **Support may be dropped in the future, without notice,** if new
>   functionality is implemented that cannot be made to work in Internet
>   Explorer 11

Are we now at the point where Internet Explorer 11 (the latest Internet Explorer version) is not supported on the SE sites? If so, I see no use for the [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) tag as bugs should no longer be reported for it. The tag would violate "**[#2)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**".

Comment: Regarding the downvotes there, I'm one who's reported a lot of IE-related bugs lately and many of them receive opinionated downvotes.

Comment: Are you saying that you would like the tag to be removed? Or are you asking if the community should remove a tag they consider off-topic/obsolete?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No. I think that would be misapplying the concept of removing off-topic tags. Questions about using the Internet Explorer browser on Stack Exchange are not off topic for this site. Legacy questions considered, the browser may no longer be supported fully, but such questions are not off topic.