# Burninate the "inappropriate-advertisements" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

Because we now have the [Report this ad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345476/report-this-ad-feature) feature, I'm requesting that this tag be removed.  (That post is not yet marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345476/report-this-ad-feature#comment1185717_345476) comment says it was released network-wide nearly a month ago).  The [inappropriate-advertisements](/questions/tagged/inappropriate-advertisements) tag has just 10 questions, all to report an inappropriate ad, and no tag wiki.  If we have a more efficient way to report inappropriate ads, is there a reason for this tag to continue existing?

**Burninate-request**:  Kill!

Comment: Wouldn't it have some usefulness in the future when we want to look back on what kind of inappropriate ads there were in the past? Not all deprecated features/aspects tags get burninated I think? Cf acceptance rate, removed badges, etc

Comment: Also, what if the same inappropriate advertisement continues to keep showing even after one's reported it? It's useful to re-report them here, or at least find out why the team decided to retain the ad after a review.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, let's not do that. Let's go over the [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate)

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Yes, it does describe the contents and it is unambiguous

- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes, reporting ads, even inappropriate ones is our core business.

- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Yes, there are related tags like [ads](/questions/tagged/ads) which have a different goal / audience / purpose.

- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

If you've seen an inappropriate ad you've seen them all, so yes, it does mean the same thing in all contexts even the common ones.

**tl;dr**

None of the criteria apply for the tag to be burned. The tag can stay.

Suggest a tag excerpt and wiki to explain its intended (historical) usage and guide users to current tags.

Comment: But... the tag is no longer the right way to report bad ads... instead of going through a box-ticking exercise, perhaps we need to put some actual human thought into this?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings If a user reports an ad through the form and the team decides to retain the ad after a review, they won't be notified of that fact or why they made that decision. They can ask here with that tag to find out why.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog Now _that_ is a sensible rationale!